# How to add delay between each recyclerview item?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to set delay time between each of my recyclerview items. I have a List of the specific time delay I want for each item. Now using the following code it works fine for fewer items but if there are 15-20 items then multiple items will start at the same time. I'm assuming it's because as other items are not displayed it considers them as the first item and starts the timer.

```
holder.timer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CountDownTimer((long) (time.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()) * 60000), 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
//timer.setText("minutes remaining: " + millisUntilFinished);
//here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                        holder.timer.setText("" + String.format(FORMAT,
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        holder.timer.setText("done!");
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        },  delay* 60000);
```

Now this works fine for 4-5 items but for 10-15 items when I scroll 2 or 3 item's timer start at the same time instead of waiting for the previous item to finish

Comment: i think you have put the timer code on wrong place. it seems you put it in binviewholder which is being instantiated every time a new view is being initialized. so initially there are 2 3 views onn screen so everything works fine but when you scroll new views are being initialized and that's what makes the timer start again

Comment: and i still didn't get what you want to accomplish. please elaborate

Comment: @HarKal Yes you understood it right, so now where should I put the timer?

Comment: please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just initialize the recyclerview with only one item,

then count the time with `System.currentTimeMillis();`,

after two second add an item in the recyclerView list and call `notifyItemInserted()` to notify the adapter that a new item is inserted.

something like this:

```
long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(now - initialTime < 2000){
    now = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
//now code after two seconds..
mainList.add(item);
adapter.notifyItemInserted();
```

Comment: I change my code to this : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uo776Jj7iyndM6yaG8exmIGGoSpA9kij   Now what happens is it shows all items at once. Please let me know how to make it right?

Comment: You are waiting for two seconds and then add whole items at once. you should add item by item of your list to your adapter and call notifyItemInserted() after each item.

Comment: That's what I tried to do by keeping the list4.add(excelextract); in the for loop. If keep the following lines out of the loop it shows error that adapter is not defined     ```adapter = new TimerListAdapter(TimerActivity.this, list4);
                            adapter.notifyItemChanged(list4.size(), list4);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);```       Please tell how to enter only one item at a time?

Comment: well, you should put lines (new TimerListAdapter and setAdapter) before your for statement. then use adapter.add(item); in "for statement" and then notifyItemChanged().